# Is is possible to write a background service that run on multiple mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I'm curious if anybody know some way to write a program in a single language for mobile devices (particularly android, ios & win phone) that run on background(no UI + start at boot time)??

**note 1: I have already checked phonegap, steroids and stuff like that.. they are not meant to be used to write background services, I'm aware..**

**note 2: I don't believe in magic. hence, I don't think there is actually a positive answer for this question. I just asked to confirm**

Comment: Your first question should be whether iOS and Windows Phone support this for any language. Android does, though you would need to implement it in Java (or something else that compiles to Java bytecodes).

Comment: what do you mean background service? native side or hybrid side?

Comment: @CommonsWare what makes android so special? just because Objective-C nor C# are compiled into java bytecode, we can't conclude android is any superior than the rest of them.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I didn't get you brother

Comment: It isn't "special" -- it is merely the one that I am in position to comment upon.